# Extern class used by an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I'm a newbie in using C# applied with ASP.NET, so I ask you of all things patience.

First the context: I developed an ASP page who takes to validate a username and a password (as shown in the first chunk of code. For effects of this question, it doesn't matter about the characters in the password box, it's irrelevant).

**Index.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Login" runat="server">
    <div><table>
    <tr>
    <td>User</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="User" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="Pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Login" 
        onclick="LoginButton_Click" /></td>
    </tr></table>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then after clicking the button "Login", the strings given in both textboxes are being compared with specific strings, and if both strings coincide, the login is successful (as shown in the second chunk of code).

**Index.aspx.WebDesigner.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication7
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LoginBoton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String user = User.Text;
            String password = Pass.Text; 

            String uservalid = "Carlos";
            String passvalid = "236";

            if((user.Equals(uservalid)) && (password.Equals(passvalid)))
                Response.Redirect("Valid.aspx");
            else
                Response.Redirect("Invalid.aspx");

        }
    }
}
```

Let's suppose in some moment **I need to create a new class specifically** for validating the login (I know it can be done with Java), and I will use it for my page. Is it necessary considering in this case I am already using the `Index.aspx.WebDesigner.cs`? And if it is necessary, or I don't have no choice but to use this new class, how can I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating classes in c# is very similar to creating classes in any modern, strongly typed, OO programming language.  First you define the class, and then you instantiate it.  There are many different ways to re-create the validation in your question, here's one.

Here is the class definition

```
public class Validator
{
  private const string Username = "Carlos";
  private const string Password = "236";

  public bool Validate(string user, string pass) 
  {
    return (user == Username && pass == Password);
  }
}
```

To instantiate and use the class in your code (note the use of the [ternary conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of if/else, this keeps the code concise and readable)

```
protected void LoginBoton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //instantiate the class defined above
  var validator = new Validator();

  //find the next page to redirect to
  var redirectTo = validator.Validate(User.Text, Pass.Text) ? "Valid.aspx" : "Invalid.aspx";

  //redirect the user
  Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
}
```

C# is a deep language with a gentle learning curve, you may benefit from finding a good tutorial or book on the subject.  [There are a number of introductory tutorials from Microsoft that may be helpful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Another thing to note, is that the word [`extern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a keyword in c#, that indicates managed code (i.e. code that runs in the [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4.aspx)) wants to load and execute unmanaged code, (i.e. code that runs natively).

Comment: I was saying "extern" class, no in the context you said, but in the context that the class is completely independent of the ASP page. But anyway, thanks for the aclaration.